# Чтение и обработка огромных файлов CSV

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, big-data

Есть 2 файла в формате .csv, размеры 60 ГБ и 1 ГБ. Мне необходимо создать на их основе таблицу по ключам из обоих файлов (по типу WHERE и JOIN в SQL), а затем экспортировать опять в файл .csv. Как мне это сделать? `pandas` такое не сможет обработать скорее всего, просто оперативки не хватит.

Comment: (недавно где-то видел в ответах или комментариях) У метода [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) есть параметр `memory_map`, который позволяет не читать файл в память, а работать с ним напрямую.

Comment: @insolor, выдает ошибку `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры входных данных (по 3-7 строк) и пример того, что должно получиться в результате, чтобы было понятно по каким критериям объединяются и фильтруются таблицы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [Dask DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) вместо Pandas. Dask умеет обрабатывать DataFrame на диске - т.е. такие, которые не помещаются в память. Обычно Dask работает гораздо медленнее Pandas и его API гораздо беднее.

Кроме этого можно прочитать в память только те столбцы, которые участвуют в объединении и фильтрации (если эти данные влезают в память), выбрать только соответствующие строки и дальше читать из CSV файлов только соответствующие строки.

Но проще всего для данных задач использовать базы данных, например MySQL или PostgreSQL - они с легкостью обрабатывают данные, которые не помещаются в памяти. Кроме этого они поддерживают индексацию, что может значительно ускорить обработку данных.

Кстати в большинстве БД существуют специальные утилиты для быстрой загрузки CSV файлов в БД: [PostgreSQL: `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html), [MySQL: `LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Тоже пришёл к решению с БД, так будет проще и быстрее всего

Comment: а можно ли использовать SQLite для этой задачи?

Comment: @Ratatuy129, можно попробовать, но SQLite гораздо беднее в плане возможностей и наверняка будет медленнее работать...