# Работа с русским форматом даты

Tags: sqlite, дата, csv

Продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028503/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-csv) вопроса. Есть бд SQLite, в которой хранятся импортированные из огромных csv файлов (60+ гб) таблицы. Проблема заключается в обработке дат этой таблицы. Так как csv хранит только текст, то и поле Дата представлено в текстовом русском формате (12.12.2019). Соответственно, при фильтрации по дате возникает проблема. Функция date() не работает или работает неверно. Есть возможность преобразовать такой тип в тип, который может быть распознан SQLite как дата?
Пример хранящихся в БД данных:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ Col1  ║ Col2  ║    Дата    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ Value ║ Value ║ 12.01.2017 ║
║ Value ║ Value ║ 01.09.2019 ║
║ Value ║ Value ║ 31.12.2018 ║
║ ...   ║ ...   ║ ...        ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datefield = SUBSTR(value_ru,7) || '-' || SUBSTR(value_ru,4,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(value_ru,1,2)
```

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо. Как-то не допер использовать простую конкатенацию